# Use XmlReader to get a name and value from an XML File in VB.NET

Tags: xml, vb.net, xmlreader

I am using the following XML file and VB code. I want to be able to get the project name which is in the project tag and also the value of whatever is between the  tags. Getting the "Name" value works fine, but I can't seem to figure out how to read any of the sub-items. I want to populate a ListView or possibly a DataGrid with 2 columns of data:

```
project   |  description
------------------------
file001   |  ABC Project
file002   |  DEF Project
```

The XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<menu>
    <header>
        <listname>Files list</listname>
        <lastlistupdate>02/08/2018</lastlistupdate>
    </header>
    <project name="file001" index="true" image="'">
        <description>ABC Project</description>
        <month>January</month>
    </project>
    <project name="file002" index="true" image="'">
        <description>DEF Project</description>
        <month>February</month>
    </project>
        <project name="file003" index="true" image="'">
        <description>Not really important project</description>
        <month>March</month>
    </project>
</menu>
```

What is odd about this code is that the "IF" test passes which means xr.Name must be "project". However, my log test line (xr.Name.ToString) shows .Name is "description". I don't understand how.

```
Dim xmlfile As String = ""
Dim filename As String = ""
Dim title As String = ""
ListViewFiles.Items.Clear()
xmlfile = Application.StartupPath & "\projectlist.xml"

Dim xr As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(xmlfile)
While xr.Read()
    If xr.NodeType = XmlNodeType.Element AndAlso xr.Name = "project" Then
        filename = xr.GetAttribute(0) 'Gets "name" correctly (ex: file001)
        title = Trim(xr.ReadString()) '<<<<-- will not work
        WriteLog("xr.name: " & xr.Name.ToString) <-shows the tag "description"???
        ListViewFiles.Items.Add(New ListViewItem(New String() {filename, title}))
    End If
End While
xr.Close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get VS to make a class which corresponds to the XML file, and then you can use that class to get the data, sometimes very simply.

I put a DataGridView on a Form and used this code:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Serialization

Public Class Form1

    Class Project
        Property Filename As String
        Property Description As String
    End Class

    Private Sub LoadData()
        Dim xmlFile = "C:\temp\projectlist.xml"
        Dim projectsData As Projects.menu

        Dim serializer = New XmlSerializer(GetType(Projects.menu))
        Using fs As New FileStream(xmlFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)
            Using rdr = XmlReader.Create(fs)
                projectsData = DirectCast(serializer.Deserialize(rdr), Projects.menu)
            End Using
        End Using

        Dim projectsList = projectsData.project.Select(Function(p) New Project With {.Filename = p.name, .Description = p.description}).ToList()

        DataGridView1.DataSource = projectsList

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        LoadData()
        DataGridView1.AutoResizeColumn(0)
        DataGridView1.AutoResizeColumn(1)

    End Sub

End Class
```

To get this:

[image]

Please adjust the names of classes and properties as needed.

Of course, you need the class to go with the XML file. To do that, copy the XML data and then in Visual Studio choose "Edit"->"Paste Special"->"Paste XML as classes". I chose to paste it into a class named "Projects" and got this:

```
Public Class Projects

    <System.SerializableAttribute(),
 System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code"),
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType:=True),
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute([Namespace]:="", IsNullable:=False)>
    Partial Public Class menu

        Private headerField As menuHeader

        Private projectField() As menuProject

        '''<remarks/>
        Public Property header() As menuHeader
            Get
                Return Me.headerField
            End Get
            Set
                Me.headerField = Value
            End Set
        End Property

        '''<remarks/>
        <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("project")>
        Public Property project() As menuProject()
            Get
                Return Me.projectField
            End Get
            Set
                Me.projectField = Value
            End Set
        End Property
    End Class

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.SerializableAttribute(),
System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code"),
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType:=True)>
    Partial Public Class menuHeader

        Private listnameField As String

        Private lastlistupdateField As String

        '''<remarks/>
        Public Property listname() As String
            Get
                Return Me.listnameField
            End Get
            Set
                Me.listnameField = Value
            End Set
        End Property

        '''<remarks/>
        Public Property lastlistupdate() As String
            Get
                Return Me.lastlistupdateField
            End Get
            Set
                Me.lastlistupdateField = Value
            End Set
        End Property
    End Class

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.SerializableAttribute(),
System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code"),
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType:=True)>
    Partial Public Class menuProject

        Private descriptionField As String

        Private monthField As String

        Private nameField As String

        Private indexField As Boolean

        Private imageField As String

        '''<remarks/>
        Public Property description() As String
            Get
                Return Me.descriptionField
            End Get
            Set
                Me.descriptionField = Value
            End Set
        End Property

        '''<remarks/>
        Public Property month() As String
            Get
                Return Me.monthField
            End Get
            Set
                Me.monthField = Value
            End Set
        End Property

        '''<remarks/>
        <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()>
        Public Property name() As String
            Get
                Return Me.nameField
            End Get
            Set
                Me.nameField = Value
            End Set
        End Property

        '''<remarks/>
        <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()>
        Public Property index() As Boolean
            Get
                Return Me.indexField
            End Get
            Set
                Me.indexField = Value
            End Set
        End Property

        '''<remarks/>
        <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()>
        Public Property image() As String
            Get
                Return Me.imageField
            End Get
            Set
                Me.imageField = Value
            End Set
        End Property
    End Class


End Class
```

P.S. I put the encoding in the XML file's declaration: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>`.

Comment: Wow, outside the box thinking. Much more than a simple answer to my problem, a whole new way to do it. And what if I want to load the XML file into a database and have that database linked to the DataGridView so that I can save the file and load it later for editing. I am going with your DataGridView idea, adding a checkbox column, and then delete all the projects on a drive that are checked and remove the rows for those items that were deleted.

Comment: Loading the XML file into a database and having that database linked to the DataGridView so that it can be saved and loaded later for editing is a bit too far from the original question to carry on with that aspect in this Q&A ;)

Comment: Fair enough! When you loaded the xml and used "Paste XML as Classes", you got the entire file, I am assuming. My actual file would take 10 minutes to process. I gave you a subset that repeats for the entire XLM file.  Would an XML file with just 1 record or 2 or 3 do the job, or must I use the entire file?

Comment: Just a representative sample of the file will be enough - if there are repeated entities you would need to include more than one so that it can tell they are repeated. So, just 2 or 3 should do the job.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote this code for your XML to get the file name(project/name) and the title (description). I hope you can understand it :)

```
Dim filename As String = ""
Dim title As String = ""
Dim XMLReader As XmlReader = XMLReader.Create(xmlfile)
With XMLReader
    'As long as the reader hasnt come to the end of the document, this loop is executed'
    Do While .Read
    If .IsStartElement() Then
        Select Case .Name
        Case "project"
            filename = .GetAttribute(0)
            Console.WriteLine(filename)
        Case "description"
            title = .ReadElementString
            Console.WriteLine(title)
            Console.WriteLine("Found: " & filename & " - " & title) 
            'you can place your "final" code here.'
            Exit Select
        Case Else
            .Read()
            'continue reading if nothing is special'
        End Select
    End If
    Loop
    .Close() 'close the reader. All done!'
End With
```

You can test the code here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/3CDd6Q

In your original code was some mistakes like you used `xr.Name` to get the element of the description tag but with `.Name` you only get the name of the `<name>` tag. You need to use `.ReadElementString` if you want to get the element between the `<>element<>` tags.

Comment: Hard to pick the actual answer! This solved exactly what I was asking for and taught me about dotnetfiddle. The other answer gave me a whole new way of looking at it. I am using this method now and learning the other. Works perfectly. Is there a way to know in a stream reader like this what the "count" of all the things it has to go through is, or does it not know until it's done? I would like a progress bar if possible. The actual XML file is thousands of items long and takes several minutes.